# eQuery not returning all valid results

Tags: sql

I have a table called `StepAndStatus`, that has over one million rows, and no primary key. I have an outside process that runs once a day, and only pulls the last 24 hours of data (based on the status event date). Every now and then I get duplicates from an outside process (that I cannot control), that I try to weed out in a stored procedure that contains this query:

```
Begin
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY StepName, StatusName, StatusEventDate, CandidateID ORDER BY CandidateID desc) AS [rn]
    FROM StepANDStatus
)
DELETE from cte WHERE [rn] > 1; 
End;
```

When I run this query, I am given the statement of however many rows were affected/deleted. However, when I run the select version of the delete query the next day, I am given results from previous days (sometimes a whole month before present day) that should have been caught everyday up to the current date. Is there a reason my query isn't returning every row? I have compared the IDs of the duplicate from one day to the next, and they are completely unique.

Comment: I think you're going to need to show us some malfunctioning data here.  Duplicates in your query are defined by the four columns in the partition, not by what you imagine otherwise.

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking? I don't think I'm imagining anything... I ran the query two days ago and I was returned 74 results that I proved were duplicates, and deleted. I ran the same query today, and rows that are older that the past 48 hours show up, not being caught the first time I ran this query.

Comment: Define duplicate.  Which columns are you looking at?

Comment: The four listed above: Stepname, statusname, statuseventdate, and candidateID. If any two rows have complete matches for those four columns, then they are duplicates

Comment: So you are saying that you delete duplicates but they reappear the next day?  Some reproducible data would help here.  By the way, your query looks fine to me.

Comment: Hope there are no chances of data(past records which are older than 48 hrs) modified or created after the first run of this query two days ago. Right?

Comment: Not quite, but close. When I delete the rows, they are gone for good, that candidate no longer is giving me duplicates. The next day, a completely new set of duplicates, from rows that older than the time-frame that I am pulling are being returned. This new set of data SHOULD have been presented the last time the query ran, but was not. I don't know what data I could post unless it was the whole table, and you tested the query against it over several days.

Comment: Rex - No, once I have inserted data, it does not get modified by any query.

Comment: Is the daily process that adds new data possibly adding previously-deleted duplicates because those rows are seen as 'new' because they exist in the outside data source but not (any more) in your database?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Comment: RD - No, data from a week ago is being returned in my query (though my SP should have deleted it every day since), and only data from the past 24 hours is uploaded.
Horse - Microsoft SQL Server